# Serenity BDD - Can I define step in such way that Cucumber datatable columns contains only allowed values?

Tags: datatable, cucumber, gherkin, serenity-bdd

I have following step:

```
And I verify results for 'param1AllowedValue1' with 'param2AllowedValue3'
```

that is defined in following way:

```
@And("{word} verify results for {param1} with {param2}")
public void someMethod(String nameOfActor, Param1 param1, Param2 param2) {}

@ParameterType("'(param1AllowedValue1|param1AllowedValue2|param1AllowedValue3)'")
public Param1 param1(String param1) {return ...}

@ParameterType("'(param2AllowedValue1|param2AllowedValue2|param2AllowedValue3)'")
public Param2 param1(String param2) {return ...}
```

which immediatelly makes it easy to see if I have *Not* used correct value for param1 or param2: IDE shows step as not recognized one.

---

Now I want to redefine the step, so that instead of repeating steps:

```
And I verify results for 'param1AllowedValue1' with 'param2AllowedValue3'
And I verify results for 'param1AllowedValue2' with 'param2AllowedValue2'
And I verify results for 'param1AllowedValue3' with 'param2AllowedValue1'
```

I could use only one step with datatable:

```
And I verify results for:
| param1              | param2               |
| param1AllowedValue1 | param2AllowedValue3  | 
| param1AllowedValue2 | param2AllowedValue2  |
| param1AllowedValue3 | param2AllowedValue1  |
```

My question is how can I make it possible that param1 and param2 values will be verified against the allowed values - the same as in case of parameter type.

I've found only an example when values are just read from the Datatable, not verified: https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/configuration/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Cucumber by mapping your table to a `List<Parameters>` where:

```java
record Parameters(P1 p1, P2 p2)

enum P1 { Value1, Value2 }
enum P2 { Value1, Value2 }
```

Then your mapping tool can tell you that the value was not valid.

For example using

```java
public class DataTableStepDefinitions {

   private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

   @DefaultParameterTransformer
   @DefaultDataTableEntryTransformer
   @DefaultDataTableCellTransformer
   public Object defaultTransformer(Object fromValue, Type toValueType) {
       return objectMapper.convertValue(fromValue, objectMapper.constructType(toValueType));
   }
}
```

Docs:

- https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/java#data-table-type
- https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/datatable

Notes:

- Unfortunately there is no IDE integration for data tables.
- This works for Cucumber, I don't know if it will work with Serenity.